# Почему нет записи в переменную?

Tags: python, ftp

Понадобилось сделать некий код для взаимодействия с ftp. Не могу понять почему взаимодействие происходит именно так. Например для модуля OS

```
from os import listdir
a = listdir()
print(a)
['.DS_Store', '.localized', 'create_subnets.py', 'Father movie', 'remove_ftp.py']
```

Однако для ftp получить содержимое в переменную, а именно в list можно только так:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("ip address")
ftp.login("login", "pass")

lines = []
b = ftp.dir(('path'), lines.append)
```

Передать значение на ftp a = ftp.dir('path') нельзя. Почему в ftp так?

Comment: Это вопрос к разработчикам модуля. Или вы это риторический вопрос задали, типа: "почему люди не летают и в ftp содержимое каталога передается странным образом"?

Comment: может вот так: `a = list(ftp.dir('path'))`

Comment: Нет, так не работает.